# Не логинится в instagram

Tags: instagram, бот

Получил, сначала code, потом access_token.
Пытаюсь залогиниться к instagram используя access_token.

```
private function Auth() {
    $this->inLog("Auth");
    $login = $this->makeApiCall('accounts/login/', $this->user, true, false);
    if(isset($login['status']) && $login['status'] == 'ok') {
        $this->inLog("Login success..\nLogged in as ".$login['logged_in_user']['username']); //todo msgs in array
        $this->is_logged = true;
        $this->user = $login['logged_in_user'];
    } else die($this->inLog('Wrong username/password'));
}

public function makeApiCall($method, $params = [], $ssl = false, $use_cookie = true) {
    $defaultRequestBody = [
        "device_id"=>'android-'.$this->GUID,
        "guid"=>$this->GUID,
        "Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    ];
    if(!empty($params)) {
        $params = json_encode(array_merge($defaultRequestBody, $params));
        $signedBody = 'signed_body='.$this->generateSig($params).".".urlencode($params).'&ig_sig_key_version='.self::$key_ver;
    }
    return json_decode($this->curl->call(($ssl ? 'https:' : 'http:').self::$apiURL.$method, $signedBody, $use_cookie), true);
}
```

Вроде всё должно работать, вылетаю с неверный логин и пароль.
Может проблема с access_token? со старым access_token всё работает.
Тогда непонятно, как можно получить access_token, с правами лайкинга и фолоувинга? Теперь..

Comment: Укажите язык программирования.

Comment: php, разобрался в чем проблема. в том, что нету permission на свежереги. придется пойти другим каким то путём.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была связана со свежерегами. Те, кто новые регистрировались после 6 ноября 2016 года (если память не изменяет). Уже не имели прав для определенных действий. И для того, чтобы полноценно использовать API надо подавать заявку на модерацию вашего app.